# How to use Protobuf's timestamp library with Go's time library

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

Import from `github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp` gives a native timestamp implementation by Protobuf, could be used inside of your protobuf definitions to represent time. A closer look at the `timestamp.pb.go` file provided looks like it generated some `struct` like this:

```
type Timestamp struct {
    Seconds int64 `protobuf:"varint,1,opt,name=seconds,proto3" json:"seconds,omitempty"`
    Nanos                int32    `protobuf:"varint,2,opt,name=nanos,proto3" json:"nanos,omitempty"`
    XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral struct{} `json:"-"`
    XXX_unrecognized     []byte   `json:"-"`
    XXX_sizecache        int32    `json:"-"`
}
```

There are some commented examples inside the `timestamp.pb.go` but I'm not understanding it very well.

To use it in relation with go's `time` [library](https://golang.org/pkg/time/). I'm not sure how I'm suppose to set the fields inside of `Timestamp`. I assuming "conversion" between the two types aren't difficult, but I'm quit new to Go and protobuf. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check out gogoproto,it has support for doing that mapping for you https://github.com/gogo/protobuf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert this manually into time.Time.

For non-pointer values:

```
if !u.Timestamp.IsZero() {
    timestamp, _ := ptypes.TimestampProto(u.Timestamp)
    up.Timestamp = timestamp
}
```

For pointer values:

```
if u.Timestamp != nil {
    timestamp, _ := ptypes.TimestampProto(*u.Timestamp)
    up.Timestamp = timestamp
}
```

Comment: What is `u`, `up`, and `ptypes`?

Comment: u and up are irrelevant structs, containing time.Time fields. (u is a generated proto struct, up is database model struct).

Ptypes is an import that converts proto timestamp to Go ones.